# Is it possible to compose Maybe operations with the new version of Nan?

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

Nan 2.0, for compatibility with Node 4.0, [introduced `Maybe` and `MaybeLocal` types](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/maybe_types.md), and several functions that return them. However, most of them do not seem to *accept* `Maybe` objects, and in several cases I would want to compose those methods. For example (assuming I have a function that returns a `MaybeLocal<String>`), I would like to do `return Nan::To<String>(Nan::Get(object, key))` instead of

```
Nan::MaybeLocal<Value> maybe_value = Nan::Get(object, key);
if (maybe_value.IsEmpty()) {
  return Nan::Nothing;
}
return Nan::To<String>(maybe_value.ToLocalChecked());
```

Is there a reasonable way to do this without writing my own wrapper around every one of these functions?

Comment: I thought that just returning `maybe_value.ToLocalChecked()` would do this.   

Since the `MaybeLocal` template will return `Nothing` in the empty instance, and a `String` in the filled instance, do you need to handle all the casting yourself, or are you just overkilling it?

Comment: `maybe_value` has type `MaybeLocal<Value>`, so `maybe_value.ToLocalChecked()` has type `Local<Value>`.

Comment: What would the return type of this function be?  What allows NaN::Nothing and Local<Value>?

Comment: "assuming I have a function that returns a `MaybeLocal<String>`". `Nan::To<T>` has return type `MaybeLocal<T>`.

Comment: Net result, this function returns a ```MaybeLocal<String>``` that could potentially be empty?

```Nan::To<String>(Nan::Get(object, key));``` would do the exact same thing, right?   ```Nan::To<>()``` returns a ```Maybe<>``` for cases like this, where conversion fails.

Comment: The whole point of this question is that `Nan::Get` returns a `MaybeLocal<Value>` and the argument to `Nan::To<T>` is a `Local<Value>`, so you can't do `Nan::To<String>(Nan::Get(object, key));`

Comment: I apologize for being slow on the uptake, but there's something that just doesn't make sense to me here.


This may convert the underlying type from ```v8::Value``` to ```v8::String```, but still leaves the function consumer having to check for Empty value.  What's the value added?


I'm still learning Nan, so I'm no expert, just trying to help out.

Comment: The point here is not to expose the code I wrote as an entire function. The point is that it takes 5 lines to express something that should reasonably be expressible in one line, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it than what I have.